# Question regarding custom collections in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I would like to know what is the best pattern when returning objects from custom collection classes. To illustrate my problem, here is an example:

I have a Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
   //properties
   //methods
}
```

Then I have a customer collection class:

```
public class Customercollection: Collection<Customer>
{

  public Collection<Customer> FindCustomers()
   {
     //calls DAL and gets a Collection of customers
     Collection<Customer> customers = DAL.GetCustomers();

     return customers;
   }
}
```

Now, an alternative version of this method can be:

```
public class Customercollection: Collection<Customer>
{

  public Collection<Customer> FindCustomers()
   {
     //calls DAL and gets a Collection of customers
     Collection<Customer> customers = DAL.GetCustomers();
     foreach(Customer c in customers)
     this.Add(c);
     return this;
   }
}
```

I would like to discuss Which one is the better approach? And is there any other approach better than two above two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would propose a third approach:

**Edit:** *I have updated this code example to reflect the OP's comments below.*

```
public class Customer
{
    public static ICollection<Customer> FindCustomers()
    {
        Collection<Customer> customers = new Collection<Customer>();

        foreach (CustomerDTO dto in DAL.GetCustomers())
            customers.Add(new Customer(dto));  // Do what you need to to create the customer

        return customers;
    }
}
```

Most of the time a custom collection is not needed - I am assuming that this is one of those cases.  Also you can add utility methods onto the type (in this case, the `Customer` type) as this aids developer discovery of these methods.  (This point is more a matter of taste - since this is a static method you are free to put it in whatever type you wish `CustomerUtility` or `CustomerHelper` for example).

My final suggestion is to return an interface type from `FindCustomers()` to give you greater flexibility in the future for implementation changes.  Obviously `DAL.GetCustomers()` would have to return some type that implemented `IList<T>` as well but then any API method (especially in a different tier like a data layer) should be returning interface types as well.

Comment: My DAL is returning a Collection of DTOs, like Collection<CustomerDTO> and in my BL method I am creating a collection of actual business objects from 
these DTOs, like:


Collection<CustomerDTO> dtoList = DAL.GetCustomers();
Collection<Customer> customers = new Collection<Customer>();
foreach(CustomerDTO dto in dtoList)
{
  Customer customer = new Customer(dto); //copy constructor here which fills the objects properties
  customers.Add(customer);
  
}
return customers;

Comment: Thank you for your reply! One small question, in this link: 

http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx

Cwalina mentions in his comment that:

"We recommend using Collection<T>, ReadOnlyCollection<T>, or KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem> for outputs and properties and interfaces 
IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>, IList<T> for inputs."

Does that mean we should return Collection<> instead of IList<>? Just want to know your opinion on this.

Comment: I personally dislike returning concrete types from API calls but the important thing I take from that article is to not use `List<T>` as a return type for the reasons stated. That being said I think you _could_ use `Collection<T>` as a return type but I would still suggest either `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, or `IEnumerable<T>` for a return type.

Comment: Also, nothing precludes you from returning a `Collection<T>` as an `ICollection<T>` - this would be your best option I think, especially after reading that article you linked.  I will update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: @Andrew - The only change I'd like to propose is to rename this class as CustomerRepository that returns an ICollection<Customer> when static FindCustomer() is called.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion both of them are a bit weird and confusing. When you extend the Collection class you kind of imply that your class IS a collection - so that it contains the data. I think when you make this method static in the first case it will make the most sense:

```
public class Customercollection: Collection<Customer>
{

  public static Collection<Customer> FindCustomers()
   {
     //calls DAL and gets a Collection of customers
     Collection<Customer> customers = DAL.GetCustomers();

     return customers;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want those methods on the CustomerCollection class then I would suggest

```
public static ICollection<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
```

or

```
public void FillWithAllCustomers()
```

However, I'd argue that your CustomerCollection class is redundant and consumers can go directly to the DAL if they want to get a collection of customer objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way would be:

```
public class Customercollection: Collection<Customer>
{
}

public class Customer
{
    public static CustomerCollection FindCustomers()
    {
        return DAL.GetCustomers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put the FindCustomers method in the DAL class or create a Finder class to hold the method. Chances are you will need more finder methods later.

Answer (score 0):

You extend Collection in your first example but you never use Customercollection to store any customers. Instead you are returning a Collection<Customer>. My suggestion is:

```
public static class Customers
{

  public static Collection<Customer> FindCustomers()
   {
     //calls DAL and gets a Collection of customers
     Collection<Customer> customers = DAL.GetCustomers();

     return customers;
   }
}
```

Used like this:

```
Collection<Customer> customers = Customers.FindCustomers();
```

Your second example is also a little weird, because if you call FindCustomers twice you will get each customer two times in the list.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like this:

```
public class CustomerCollection: Collection<Customer>
{
  public CustomerCollection: : base(new List<Customer>())
   {}

  public static IList<Customer> FindCustomers()
  {
   //return them from DAL
  }
}
```

Using List in your constructor will let you use useful's methods in List in your class without the need to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this extension method to Andrew's suggestion:

```
public static Collection<T> ToCollection(this IEnumerable<T> seq) {
    return new Collection<T>(seq.ToList());
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public static Collection<Customer> FindCustomers() { 
    return DAL.GetCustomers().Select(dto => new Customer(dto)).ToCollection();
}
```

Or if you go with Andrew's advice about returning interface types,

```
public static IList<Customer> FindCustomers() { // or ICollection
    return DAL.GetCustomers().Select(dto => new Customer(dto)).ToList();
}
```